# Is there any Node.js based data transformation/mapping tool?

Tags: node.js, transformation

I'd need something like Smooks but that could execute on Node.js.
I have the need of transforming various XML formats to/from other formats and also CSV, EDI, etc.

The tool should contain some format tool where you can define the format and then some mapping component to map input format to output format.

Comment: Have you searched [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) library?

Comment: Yes, but didn't come up with anything useful...

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this lib [xml2rec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2rec)?

Comment: Thanks but it seems to be using Python... I'd need a "pure" Node.js implementation to run in Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk...